# How to create multiple executable JARs from one module using Eclipse/Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

We use Maven to build an Eclipse Java module. Several of the classes in the module have main functions and we would like to create an executable JAR file for each of them. Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: Is using Gradle an option instead of Maven? I think Gradle might make this a bit easier.

Comment: @E-Riz. No, Maven it is.

Comment: Wouldn't be difficult using ANT or SBT possibly with something like sbt-assembly to do this. It's almost certainly possible in Maven or Gradle also. Or you could write a Java program to scan through the classes in the JAR and construct a new JAR based on the classes that have main methods using reflection. Lots of ways of achieving this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to define multiple executions of the plugin you're using to make an executable JAR.

One good approach would be to use the [`maven-shade-plugin`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) to make the [executable jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/executable-jar.html). All the common configuration is placed in the execution-independent section, which in this case, just specifies to attach the shaded JAR to the build. Then each execution only defines the main class to use and the classifier of the resulting Maven artifact.

In the following example configuration, there are 2 executable JARs created, the first with `Class1` as main class and the second with `Class2` as main class.

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.3</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>class1</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>my.main.Class1</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <shadedClassifierName>class1</shadedClassifierName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
    <execution>
      <id>class2</id>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>shade</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <transformers>
          <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
            <mainClass>my.main.Class2</mainClass>
          </transformer>
        </transformers>
        <shadedClassifierName>class2</shadedClassifierName>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
  <configuration>
    <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: I am confused. Can the META-INF/MANIFEST.MF be removed then?